# PostgreSQL subquery issue: give artist's song titles that matches song titles from other artists

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I can't figure out why my code doesn't work with subqueries in postgreSQL (issue below).

**Issue:** give the titles of the songs of Leonard Cohen whose title also exists as a songtitle of another artist.

Code:

```
select track.title
from (select title, name, artistid
      from artist inner join
           track
           USING(artistid)
      where name = 'Leonard Cohen'
     ) AS loli inner join
     track on track.title = loli.title
```

**EDIT**: feel pretty dumb after reading that hint, obviously I'm "matching" songs in a small list with the same songs on a bigger list. I meant to MATCH them in, not join them on their same names. I'm probably going to need a WHERE and EXISTS()

My thoughts: basically made a combined subquery of artist (containing artistid and name) and track (containing trackid, artistid, title, etc...) and gave the alias 'loli'. this contains 31 songs. Now that subquery is supposed to inner join on the track table (because titles in the subquery need to match titles in track, right?), but instead of showing me the matching tracks, it shows me 33 tracks.

Basically it had to show me only 2 tracks, but instead returned 31 tracks and 2 multiples.

Comment: Hint:  A track matches itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. songs of Leonard Cohen
2. songtitles of other artists
3. which ones exist in 1 and 2?

1.

```
select title, name, artistid
from artist 
inner joint track USING(artistid)
where name = 'Leonard Cohen'
```

2.

```
select title, name, artistid
from artist 
inner joint track USING(artistid)
where name <> 'Leonard Cohen'
```

3.

```
select title, name, artistid
from artist 
inner joint track USING(artistid)
where name = 'Leonard Cohen'
and title IN (
        select title
        from artist 
        inner joint track USING(artistid)
        where name <> 'Leonard Cohen'
       )
```

There are other approaches to 3, using `inner join` or using `exists` but IN() seemed ok to me.

```
Everybody knows, everybody knows 
That's how it goes 
Everybody knows…
```